# SQL Server locks pages in memory w/o having permission to do so

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Strange thing here:

```sql
SELECT sql_memory_model_desc
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info;
```

The query returns `LOCK_PAGES`. But the corresponding policy (`[...] - Local Security Setting - Lock pages in memory`) is empty. SQL Server 2017 Standard Edition runs with a local account.

So how is that possible?

Comment: what is your sql server service account? `select service_account, *
from sys.dm_server_services`
Localsystem has the SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME enabled https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/localsystem-account

Comment: It's indeed LocalSystem. Thanks for that!